Can I get access to a pytest hook to inject my logic AFTER the junit XML results file has been created?
From reading the docs I see that the latest hook after a test class has completed is pytest_runtest_logfinish. However, when I implement that hook and use the debugger, I see that the XML file (specified by --junitxml has yet to be created).
The reason I'd like to do this is because I want to automatically archive the XML file to my private CI system (different host), but I'd need access to the XML file.
Approaches that don't work for me:

I can access the report object from the
pytest_runtest_logreport hook, but that does not fulfill my needs (unless I can force the output of the XML file from here).
I need the completed XML file.
I can just upload this as a second command after the pytest process exits, but I want my users to be able to get this automagically without having to set it up.

I've gotten everything else working, I just want to be able to do this in pytest itself. Is there a way to force the XML file creation or to inject my logic after the report has been created? Any other suggestsions?
Thanks!!

The pytest_sessionfinish hook is called after the test run is completed, just before exiting back to the system.

Dan is correct.
I misunderstood the pytest_sessionfinish hook. It does indeed create the report and is supposedly the final step before returning the return code for the whole process. I was able to inject my logic here.
Thanks!
